# How to sort a MultiMap/TreeMultimap?

Tags: java, sorting, key-value, multimap

I wanna sort a key value multimap (1:n) by key ascending (e.g. int number).

my code is:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, myObject> mappy = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Now the given map could be:

```
KEY   VALUE
1     myObject_1 
1     myObject_2
3     myObject_3
5     myObject_4
6     myObject_5
4     myObject_6
```

I need to process all value objects in ascending order: key 1, 3, 4, 5, 6...

How can I get the sequence easily?

Any approach that I could try?

Comment: What about using SortedSetMultimap?

Comment: Well, there are several issues: 1) unless the map is a sorted map you can't sort if (e.g. a tree map is sortable, a hash map isn't), 2) the output you've posted would be like sorting the entry set so you might want to get all the entries (how you'd do that depends on the library you're using), put them into a list and then sort that based on key first and value second. That sorting would not be reflected by the map though.

Comment: As of Java 8 using a `Map<Key,Collection<Value>>` isn't that hard anymore so you might want to settle for that. In that case you could use a `TreeMap<Key,TreeSet<Value>>` to have automatic sorting within the keys and values for each key.